# What would be the sample number if two variables have different number of samples?

Tags: statistics, correlation, pearson-correlation

While correlating two variables, which have different number of samples in each, how can I find the df?

Eg.
Sample-A has 35 observations,
Sample-B has 22 observations,

How to calculate df (N)-2?

Whether 35-2 or 22-2?

Comment: Statistics questions not involving a programming problem should be posted on https://stats.stackexchange.com, not here.